# Behat - Using an example table String in an xpath selector array

Tags: php, behat, mink

I have been using Behat for a year or so at a level fine for the automation of most websites but I now need to start using it more for user generated content, I am relatively new to PHP and at the moment I am struggling how to use a String entered in an Example table in an x-path array:

```
Feature: Campaign

Scenario Outline: Pass campaign string to xpath array

Then I add a new campaign name of "<campaign>"

Examples:
|campaign  |
|Automation|
```

The context file looks like this

```
/**
 * @Then /^I add a new campaign name of "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iAddANewCampaignNameOf($campaign)
{
    /**
     * @var CreateCampaign $createCampaign
     */
    $createCampaign= $this->getPage('CreateCampaign');
    $createCampaign->campaignName($campaign);
}
```

Then I use the Page Object extension for the class Campaign.php

```
class CreateCampaign extends AutomationPage
{
protected $path = 'someURL';

public $campaign;

protected $elements = array(
    'campaignHeader' => array('xpath' => "//*[@id='site-navigation-campaigns']"),
);

public function campaignName ($campaign)
{
    $this->campaign = $campaign;
    $this->getSession()->wait(5000);
    $this->getElement('campaignName')->setValue($campaign);
}
```

So far so good, the tester can enter a campaign name of "Automation" - it gets passed through the context file and the campaign name is set in the browser.

What I am lacking is to be able to retain this $campaign name string and use it in another page so I can reference it in another array i.e. for selecting an existing campaign as follows:

```
SecondPageObjectPage.php

class ReferenceCampaign extends AutomationPage
{
protected $path = 'someURL';


protected $elements = array(
    'referenceCampaign' => array('xpath' => "//*[contains(@id,'***HERE I NEED TO GET THE 
    $campaign value"),
);              

public function editExistingCampaign ($campaign)
    {
    $this->getElement('referenceCampaign')->click();
    }
}
```

I have tried my best to simplify things and I can explain further if any of this isnt clear - hopefully its just a simple PHP question and not really Behat specific

Comment: Fix your code, update the question and if it doesn't work we'll see what else might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's a simple question, but I think that I am missing a point. If all you want is to get hold of the value that was used on the page then you need to review your code structure. First, you cannot pass method argument to the property definition in another class, but you can find the element inside `editExistingCampaign`.

```
class ReferenceCampaign extends AutomationPage
{
    protected $path = 'someURL';

    public function editExistingCampaign ($campaign)
    {
        $element = $this->find('xpath', '//*[contains(@id, "' . $campaign . '")]');

        if (isset($element)) {
            $element->click();
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Element not found');
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you are using Symfony Page Object extension, which you should mention. I'm not sure if I've got the syntax right, but the idea is to find your element inside the method.

Comment: Sorry that is just the bold code on this site, I will edit that out

Comment: Sorry, updated the answer. We normally comment on answers and accept them if they help, not use answers for comments ;) From looking at the above, does it mean that your `id` must contain both things? If so you can do it like this `'//*[contains(@id, "' . $campaign . '") and contains(@id, "actionbuttons")]'`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ian

Your example is a much better way of doing things, I have only recently started using partial contains and it expands the flexibility of finding stubborn xpaths especially if you combine more than one, like the working example below:

```
public function editExistingCampaign ($campaign)
{
    $this->getSession()->wait(5000);
    $element = $this->find('xpath', '//*[contains(@id,"'.$campaign.'")]                                                                                                            
    [contains(@id,"actionbuttons")]');

    if (isset($element)) {
        $element->click();
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Element not found');
    }

}
```

The only slight change was to add a ] at the end of the x-path